# using a button inside a bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to use a button to call the "Edit" action method from a controller named "Students", the following is my code:

```
<script>
$("#table1").bootstrapTable({

    columns: [
        { field: 'fn', title: "First Name" }, { field: 'ln', title: "Last Name" }, { field: 'gender', title: "Gender" },
        { field: 'totalmarks', title: "Total Marks" }, { field: "totalcourses", title: "Total Courses Enrolled In" },
        {field: 'links', title: "Actions"}
        ],
    data: [
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            int total = ((StudentsController)this.ViewContext.Controller).totc(@item.Id);
            @: { fn: '@item.FirstName', ln: '@item.LastName', gender: '@item.Gender', totalmarks: '@item.TotalMarks', totalcourses: '@total', 
            @: links: '<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Edit","Students")';" />' }
        ]
});
```

obviously it doesn't work, I tried using Html.ActionLink method and it worked but I need a button not a link.
I'm still new at using bootstrap table, can someone help?

**Update:** forgot to say that the Edit method expects a number to be passed to it, and this number is the item.Id from the foreach loop.

Comment: Why do you need a button??  Just style you link to look like a button. Add your ActionLink as follow:
@Html.ActionLink("action", "controller", new { parameterName: value }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" });

Comment: that's exactly what I did, I used a link with: class="btn btn-default".
and it worked good for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Edit","Students", new {id = @item.Id})' class='btn btn-default'>Edit</a>
```

Comment: ok sorry I forgot to say that the Edit action method requires the item.id to be called else it gives a "Bad request" as what happened, but it did try to invoke the method which is good, now I need to find a way to let know the id of the item from the foreach loop.

Comment: worked after a few tries, seems I had to move the closing '}' on a new line alone, if something is with it it just doesn't recognize it as a closing bracket.
so thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In the onClick event, can you can try this?

```
'<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="window.location.href="/Students/Edit/@item.Id""/>'
```

It will invoke the Edit action in the Students controller.

Comment: I'll try them now

Comment: ok the second one I tried before and tried again still didn't work.
the first one keeps saying "Unexpected String" on it.

Comment: for the first the problem is I need to append a number (Id) on it like : < 
 <  /Students/Edit/1  >, because the Edit action method expects a number which it will take from the item.Id.

Comment: it became like this:
    onclick=" window.location.href='/Students/Edit/ @item.Id'"

Comment: yes, i just realized you have to append the Id. Did it still throw the "Unxpected String" error?

Comment: yes if I append it it throws "Unexpected String" error

Comment: can you please try my edited work? Please be careful with the quotes. Make sure they are closed properly.

Comment: thanks, I just used another way a few minutes ago, and it worked as I wanted it to.
thank you for your kind help.